# Turn WebRequest Object into json string using Newtonsoft c#

Tags: c#, json, serialization, deserialization

I tried to serialize web request object using **Newtonsoft.Json** it serialize object but with empty headers.Can anyone please help me find the way

```
 WebRequest WebRequest = WebRequest.Create("http://test.com/test");
            WebRequest.Method = "Post";
            var postData = "thing1=hello";
            postData += "&thing2=world";
            var data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(postData);

            WebRequest.Headers.Add("MyTestHeader", "My Test Header Value");

            WebRequest.Method = "POST";
            WebRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            WebRequest.ContentLength = data.Length;

            Stream dataStream = WebRequest.GetRequestStream();
            // Write the data to the request stream.
            dataStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
            // Close the Stream object.
            dataStream.Close();

  Console.Writeline(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(WebRequest));
```

**Json RESULT:**

```
{
    "_HttpRequestHeaders": [
        "MyTestHeader",
        "Content-Type",
        "Host",
        "Content-Length",
        "Expect",
        "Connection"
    ],
    "_Proxy": {
        "Credentials": null
    },
    "_KeepAlive": true,
    "_Pipelined": true,
    "_AllowAutoRedirect": true,
    "_AllowWriteStreamBuffering": true,
    "_HttpWriteMode": 1,
    "_MaximumAllowedRedirections": 50,
    "_AutoRedirects": 0,
    "_Timeout": 100000,
    "_ReadWriteTimeout": 300000,
    "_MaximumResponseHeadersLength": 64,
    "_ContentLength": 25,
    "_MediaType": null,
    "_OriginVerb": {},
    "_ConnectionGroupName": null,
    "_Version": {
        "Major": 1,
        "Minor": 1,
        "Build": -1,
        "Revision": -1,
        "MajorRevision": -1,
        "MinorRevision": -1
    },
    "_OriginUri": "http://test.com/test"
}
```

Thanks in advance.I want to serialize request without any loss of information for eg: if you are making post request with some data passed to that request i want to persist that information too in my json.